# Additional field on checkout for specific payment gateway in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, checkout

I have a custom Woocommerce payment gateway and I need to add additional field on the checkout when the payment is selected.

Basically, when the users click the custom payment gateway a "select" field should appear and they have to choose something from the select field.

I have attached a screenshot to represent better the idea of what I need to do. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any info about that in the Docs.

[image: this is the image]

Comment: Can we see the code you've at least tried to implement?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following code will append to the gateway description in checkout page, a custom text input field *(here, in this example to BACS payment gateway)*:

```
// BACS payement gateway description: Append custom select field
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gateway_description', 'gateway_bacs_custom_fields', 20, 2 );
function gateway_bacs_custom_fields( $description, $payment_id ){
    //
    if( 'bacs' === $payment_id ){
        ob_start(); // Start buffering

        echo '<div  class="bacs-fields" style="padding:10px 0;">';

        woocommerce_form_field( 'field_slug', array(
            'type'          => 'select',
            'label'         => __("Fill in this field", "woocommerce"),
            'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
            'required'      => false,
            'options'       => array(
                ''          => __("Select something", "woocommerce"),
                'choice-1'  => __("Choice one", "woocommerce"),
                'choice-2'  => __("Choice two", "woocommerce"),
            ),
        ), '');

        echo '<div>';

        $description .= ob_get_clean(); // Append buffered content
    }
    return $description;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

[image]

> Related: [Validate and save additional checkout field for specific payment gateway in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53865862/validate-and-save-additional-checkout-field-for-specific-payment-gateway-in-wooc/53868329#53868329)

---

> **The complete way**, validating the field, saving it as order custom meta data and display it on orders and email notifications:
>
> [Save and display specific payment gateway additional field everywhere in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56253265/save-data-from-custom-select-field-on-checkout-to-order-and-email-woocommerce/56258209#56258209)

Comment: Thank you for your help!