# Validate and save additional checkout field for specific payment gateway in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, payment-method

I need to show an text input field when customers select BACS gateway **and I would like the input field value to be appended to orders and email notifications**.

I am using [Additional field on checkout for specific payment gateway in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52164954/additional-field-on-checkout-for-specific-payment-gateway-in-woocommerce/52168021#52168021) answer code where I have changed the select field to an input text field:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gateway_description', 'gateway_bacs_custom_fields', 20, 2 );
function gateway_bacs_custom_fields( $description, $method_id ){
    //
     if( $method_id == 'bacs' ){

        ob_start(); // Start buffering

        echo '<div  class="bacs-fields" style="padding:10px 0;">';

        woocommerce_form_field( 'field_slug', array(
            'type'          => 'text',
            'label'         => __("Udfyld EAN", "woocommerce"),
            'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
            'required'      => true,
                            ), '');
        echo '<div>';

        $description .= ob_get_clean(); // Append  buffered content
    }
    return $description;
}
```

It works fine on checkout page where it displays the field.

But the inputted text value is not being saved to orders and email notifications.

How to save and append this inputted text value on orders and email notifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of missing steps as the answer code you are using is just displaying a field in checkout under BACS payment description:

You need to *(only when BACS is the selected payment method)*:

1. Validate the field
2. Save the inputted value to the order
3. Display the field value on Order received and Order view (My account)
4. Display the field value on email notifications
5. Display the field value in admin edit order pages

So as you can see what you are asking is huge *(too broad)* and will require an additional new question for point 3, 4 and 5, where you will need to say where you want to output it *(the location)*.

All the code for steps 1 and 2:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gateway_description', 'gateway_bacs_appended_custom_text_fields', 10, 2 );
function gateway_bacs_appended_custom_text_fields( $description, $payment_id ){
     if( $payment_id === 'bacs' ){

        ob_start(); // Start buffering

        echo '<div class="bacs-fields" style="padding:10px 0;">';

        woocommerce_form_field( 'udfyld_ean', array(
            'type'          => 'text',
            'label'         => __("Udfyld EAN", "woocommerce"),
            'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
            'required'      => true,
        ), '');

        echo '<div>';

        $description .= ob_get_clean(); // Append  buffered content
    }
    return $description;
}


// Process the field (validation)
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'udfyld_ean_checkout_field_validation');
function udfyld_ean_checkout_field_validation() {
if ( $_POST['payment_method'] === 'bacs' && isset($_POST['udfyld_ean']) && empty($_POST['udfyld_ean']) )
    wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter your "Udfyld EAN" number.' ), 'error' );
}

// Save "Udfyld EAN" number to the order as custom meta data
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'save_udfyld_ean_to_order_meta_data', 10, 4 );
function save_udfyld_ean_to_order_meta_data( $order, $data ) {
    if( $data['payment_method'] === 'bacs' && isset( $_POST['udfyld_ean'] ) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( '_udfyld_ean', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['udfyld_ean'] ) );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

> To get this custom field value from **`$order`** the `WC_Order` object you will use:
>
> ```
> $udfyld_ean = $order->get_meta('_udfyld_ean');
> ```
>
> Or from **`$order_id`** the order ID you can use WordPress `get_post_meta()` function:
>
> ```
> $udfyld_ean = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_udfyld_ean', true );
> ```

The field validation *(for BACS as the selected payment method)*:

[image]

The inputted field value is saved to the order meta data (phpMyAdmin view in `wp_postmeta` table):

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot LoicTheAztec for a very usefull answer!

Comment: @tiny Thank you… Now you now how to accept an answer :) … There is a lot of threads on stack overFlow  related to points 3 to 5 that will allow you to try yourself solving what you want to do… If you ask a new question try to clearly explain the things (the display location) adding some related code…

Comment: Step 1+2 seam to work fine - I get a textinput in the right location in chekout and the validation works fine. However I don't see the inputted field value in my database (WP_postmeta table). When I make test orders. why could this be?

Comment: @tiny Just tested again and it works just perfectly on Woocommerce version 3+ (3.5.2) … So you should try to look in your database with phpMyAdmin on wp_postmeta table  for your last order ID (`post_id`) searching for the `meta_key` like `_udfyld_ean`…