# Add WC_Payment_Gateway description to Woocommerce option payment with Skrill plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, skrill

I'm using the skrill plugin for electronic payments. the plugin plugin, however, does not give me the possibility to add a description to the payment method, how can I do it using the function file? I tried to use the code on this page:

[Additional field on checkout for specific payment gateway in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52164954/additional-field-on-checkout-for-specific-payment-gateway-in-woocommerce)

but it does not work, how can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hook `woocommerce_gateway_description` can't work for SKRILL payment options as `WC_Payment_Gateway` `get_description()` is not defined in SKRILL plugin code.

So you shuld need to tweak it differently to have a description for SKRILL payment options in Woocommerce checkout page, this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gateway_icon', 'gateway_skrill_description', 10, 2 );
function gateway_skrill_description( $icon, $payment_id ){
    if ( \strpos($payment_id, 'skrill') !== false ) {
        $description_text = __("You can pay with your credit card if you don’t have a SKRILL account...", "woocommerce");
        $icon .= '</label><div class="payment_box payment_method_'.$payment_id.'" style="display:none;"><p>'.$description_text.'</p></div>';
    }
    return $icon;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

[image]

Comment: done, I'm sorry I joined recently, I do not know well the operation of the platform, however you're a big :)