# Save and display specific payment gateway additional field everywhere in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, payment-method

I am using *"[Additional field on checkout for specific payment gateway in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52164954/additional-field-on-checkout-for-specific-payment-gateway-in-woocommerce/52168021#52168021)"* answer code, that displays an additional dropdown field for specific payment gateway in checkout page.

How to save and display the options on the orders and on email notifications?

Comment: When you use an existing code *(if you don't make real changes to it)* just use the link in your question explaining what the code is doing… Also If this code is useful, don't forget to upvote the answer thread where you picked it.

Comment: Before asking a new question, please give some feed back on existing answers to your previous questions on this thread.

Answer (score 9):

> Continuation of *"[Additional field on checkout for specific payment gateway in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52164954/additional-field-on-checkout-for-specific-payment-gateway-in-woocommerce/52168021#52168021)"*

Here is the complete way to:

1. Add a dropdown with options to BACS payment
2. Field validation *(required option)*
3. Save chosen option as order custom meta data
4. Display the chosen option on order totals everywhere (orders and emails notifications)
5. Display the chosen option on admin order edit page below billing details.

The code:

```
// BACS payement gateway description: Append custom select field
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gateway_description', 'gateway_bacs_custom_fields', 20, 2 );
function gateway_bacs_custom_fields( $description, $payment_id ){
    //
    if( 'bacs' === $payment_id ){
        ob_start(); // Start buffering

        echo '<div  class="bacs-options" style="padding:10px 0;">';

        woocommerce_form_field( 'bacs_option', array(
            'type'          => 'select',
            'label'         => __("Fill in this field", "woocommerce"),
            'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
            'required'      => true,
            'options'       => array(
                ''          => __("Select something", "woocommerce"),
                'Option 1'  => __("Choice one", "woocommerce"),
                'Option 2'  => __("Choice two", "woocommerce"),
            ),
        ), '');

        echo '<div>';

        $description .= ob_get_clean(); // Append buffered content
    }
    return $description;
}

// Checkout custom field validation
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'bacs_option_validation' );
function bacs_option_validation() {
    if ( isset($_POST['payment_method']) && $_POST['payment_method'] === 'bacs'
    && isset($_POST['bacs_option']) && empty($_POST['bacs_option']) ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please Select an option for "Direct Bank Transfer" payment, please.' ), 'error' );
    }
}

// Checkout custom field save to order meta
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'save_bacs_option_order_meta', 10, 2 );
function save_bacs_option_order_meta( $order, $data ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['bacs_option']) && ! empty($_POST['bacs_option']) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( '_bacs_option' , esc_attr($_POST['bacs_option']) );
    }
}

// Display custom field on order totals lines everywhere
add_action('woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'display_bacs_option_on_order_totals', 10, 3 );
function display_bacs_option_on_order_totals( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ) {
    if ( $order->get_payment_method() === 'bacs' && $bacs_option = $order->get_meta('_bacs_option') ) {
        $sorted_total_rows = [];

        foreach ( $total_rows as $key_row => $total_row ) {
            $sorted_total_rows[$key_row] = $total_row;
            if( $key_row === 'payment_method' ) {
                $sorted_total_rows['bacs_option'] = [
                    'label' => __( "Bank wire option", "woocommerce"),
                    'value' => esc_html( $bacs_option ),
                ];
            }
        }
        $total_rows = $sorted_total_rows;
    }
    return $total_rows;
}

// Display custom field in Admin orders, below billing address block
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'display_bacs_option_near_admin_order_billing_address', 10, 1 );
function display_bacs_option_near_admin_order_billing_address( $order ){
    if( $bacs_option = $order->get_meta('_bacs_option') ) {
        echo '<div class="bacs-option">
        <p><strong>'.__('BACS option').':</strong> ' . $bacs_option . '</p>
        </div>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

**On checkout page**:

[image]

---

**On Order received page** (on Order view and email notifications):

[image]

---

**On Admin Order pages**:

[image]

Comment: Great solution! Thanks for the detailed write-up.

Answer (score 0):

add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta');

function custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta($order_id)

{

if (!empty($_POST['field_slug'])) {

update_post_meta($order_id, 'Some key',sanitize_text_field($_POST['field_slug']));

}

}
to fetch this value in order details or email template page you can use get_post_meta($order_id, 'Some key',false);