# Validation of conditional checkbox in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I validate a custom checkbox on the Woocommerce checkout page ONLY if the selected payment method is BACS?

I tried this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'add_checkout_checkbox_warning' );
function add_checkout_checkbox_warning() {
    $chosen_payment_method = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_payment_method' );
    if ( ! (int) isset( $_POST['my_checkbox'] && $chosen_payment_method == 'bacs' ) ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please agree to the checkbox.' ), 'error' );
    }
}
```

but it not working, no error message is displayed even when the checkbox is not ticked.

Comment: Did you validate the you're getting `bacs` from `$chosen_payment_method` or not?

Comment: @VijayHardaha no, how would I do this? My PHP knowledge is limited.